# Creating logourl image link in appsscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, imageurl

Is it possible to display the logo from a shared Drive file or does the file always have to appear on a hosted website? Drive image file is setup to "Anyone can view". Following a tip from another thread on stackoverflow, I changed it to the download url format, rather than the view. However no app icon appears on the sidebar - just a white space:

"logoUrl": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1q...."

I have scope defined: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
I even added https://drive.google.com under openLinkUrlPrefixes in the manifest:

Just to add - is it possible to distribute the icon with the add-on, so no link to an external website is necessary?

Thks, 
jfg

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last question first, the [Add-ons overview](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview#serve_images) describes how you don't package images with your add-on, but link out to images served elsewhere.

Regarding stuff that's saved in Drive, if you inspect an image that's shared by link (if you can open it in an incognito window your permissions are set correctly) then you can get the direct URL to the image file hosted on googleusercontent.com.

If you don't want to do that, the same docs recommend [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/), which [currently gives you 10GB per month of traffic for free](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/). [Setting it up doesn't seem too hard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart), since you'd essentially be making a "site" consisting of a single image:

1. Install NPM (left as an exercise for the reader)
2. Install Firebase stuff: `npm install -g firebase-tools`
3. Deal with auth: `firebase login` -- you'll set some things up on the Firebase console. Make note of your project name; you'll need it later.
4. Create a new directory on your PC for your "site": `mkdir ~/addon-site`
5. Put the logo there: `mv ~/Downloads/sweet-logo.png ~/addon-site`
6. Make sure you're in that directory before the next step: `cd ~/addon-site`
7. Create all of the Firebase boilerplate in this directory: `firebase init`
8. Observe that a default `index.html` was created for you: `ls`
9. Upload everything, which will be that dummy index page and your sweet logo: `firebase deploy`

If your project name was "user2793489-addon," then visiting https://user2793489-addon.firebaseapp.com/sweet-log.png should show you your sweet logo.

At this point you can get back to developing your add-on.